# Creating an ad widget

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create an ad widget. This piece of code should be re-usable by anybody. I was wondering if it is ok to use jquery in such a widget or should i be writing the entire thing in pure javascript?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend against using jQuery.  It is a large download (for those that don't already have it cached from a CDN), and is slow.  For what is contained in your widget, you aren't likely to need the bulk of what jQuery uses anyway.

That being said, if there is some element of your widget that requires jQuery, then go ahead and use it.  Just be mindful to load it from a CDN so that it will load from cache, when available.  Also keep in mind that jQuery will likely throw you over the IAB download size guidelines.

Comment: Thanks! I was initially thinking of using a plugin along with it. Now will have to rethink the design :)

Comment: @parjun, I always say, "use only what you need".  If you need jQuery, use it.  If you can do without it, definitely go without it.  You have to weigh both sides to see if it's worth it.